# Limit Exist On Multivariable Questions

Tags: calculus

There are different questions about how to prove limit in two variables does not exist when the approach from x or y does not the same. 
However, is any way to prove the limit does exist? Or when should I stop try to plug different y function into x to find the limit and stop. 
For example, $\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$
I know the limit exist, just do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Do you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using the squeeze Theorem. You can find a new function with similar but a bit larger than the function you want to prove. Prove the new function that has existed limit, and imply the squeeze theorem for it. 
for example,
$\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ when both x and y approach to 0. 
you can show $|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Prove $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq 1$ and $\frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq |y|$ 
See what you can get through this.
There is the other method called alternative method. You can replace x = rcos$\theta$ and y = rsin$\theta$
Try to see what happen when you try to get the limit for the new polar equation

Answer (score 0):

Since when you plug $x=0$ into the expression $\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ you get $0$. The candidate limit, should the limit exist, is $0$.

So, now you want to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left |\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}} -0\right |=0$. Here the problem is the denominator, so using some inequalities you want to get rid of it.

Here, one way to do it is to use the inequality $|ab|\leq a^2+b^2$. Indeed,
\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}} &\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\\
&\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}= 0
\end{align}

And since $\dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\geq 0$ we obtain $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}=0$$